# Google Apps Script - XLSX from E-mail to specific Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm getting an e-mail daily with an XLSX file that I need to then export over to a specific Google Sheet.
The code simply searches the GMAIL for a specific query, where it then gets the body (which contains a URL), which it then downloads with the doGet function, that uses the `Url.FetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob()`

After that, using the variable fileInfo, it defines, the title, mimeType of the file and the "parents" which is the ID of the folder where I need to deposit the converted file.

Then, I insert the file with the `Drive.Files.insert(fileInfo, file, {convert: true})` which should convert my Excel file and deposit it in my folder.
The export works (a file is exported). If I append a .xlsx extension manually and try to open in Excel,it opens perfectly with all the required information.

But, the issue is that I don't need to open in an Excel file, so I'm trying to export it to a Google Sheet or even parse it as a CSV, but it doesn't work.

When trying to open this exported file by ID, it says that it is missing or don't have permissions, but it is there and I do have permissions.
When checking the mime type of the file, it says "application/x-zip".

Is there anyway for me to upload the file data to my Google Sheet with the ID "1HMXgJuuRFaGK11sfR38mKh6rk4ta_Qgtlljk6HBjLkE"?

```
function CostDSP() {

  var sheetId="1HMXgJuuRFaGK11sfR38mKh6rk4ta_Qgtlljk6HBjLkE";

   var threads = GmailApp.search("from:no-reply@amazon.com subject:Cost - DSP  in:inbox newer_than:1d");
    var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
    var attachment = message.getPlainBody();


  var regex= new RegExp("\<(.*)\>");
  var url=regex.exec(attachment)[1];
  Logger.log(url);

  var file=doGet(url);

  var fileInfo = {
    title: "Cost - DSP",
    mimeType: "MICROSOFT_EXCEL",
    "parents": [{'id': "19jrt0DyfvsDz5WAdKhkekHkJ_wP7qP7f"}],
};


Drive.Files.insert(fileInfo, file, {convert: true});

var sourceFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Cost - DSP").next(); 
Logger.log(sourceFile.getMimeType());
Logger.log(sourceFile);



var source=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lIVb9YM9IK7f8dKuC1RpXjP7nLnMNXm1");
var sheet = sourceFile.getSheets()[0];
var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1HMXgJuuRFaGK11sfR38mKh6rk4ta_Qgtlljk6HBjLkE").getSheetByName('Data Intake');
sheet.copyTo(destination);

  }




function doGet(e) {
    // e.parameter["file"] //returns ?file=filelink.com/file.xlsx

   var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(e).getBlob();
  return file;

}
```

Comment: When you create the variable `fileInfo` your  attribute `mimeType` is not one to be expected. Look for the correct excel MIME, or leave it blank and let Drive figure out which one is the more appropriate (I would recommend that). Also the property of the `parents` shouldn't be declared as a string. Moreover you use both `DriveApp` or `Drive` (direct API call), is there a reason for that? You could just use [`DriveApp.createFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to use the correct mime type for import

```
mimeType:
  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
```

The next code works fine for me

```
var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
  'https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/images/9/9f/Country_Codes_and_Names.xlsx'
);

var fileInfo = {
  title: 'Cost - DSP',
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
  parents: [{
    id: 'root'
  }],
};

Drive.Files.insert(fileInfo, file, {
  convert: true
})
```

As @Raserhin said it works without the `mimeType` parameter.

```
  var fileInfo = {
    title: 'Cost - DSP',
//    mimeType:
//      'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    parents: [{ id: 'root' }],
  }
```

;

Also you can't use `doGet` as you're using now. `doGet` is a reserved function.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I also had to set the mimetype in the doGet function to the xlsx mimetype for it to work.

As an optimization I also removed the mimetype specification in the file info variable.

I'm managing to use this doGet function despite it being reserved, so I guess I'll stick to it for now?

As for calling the drive api directly, I need to use the advanced service to be able to convert the xlsx file.